# Comparing value in a table vs count of rows in other table

Tags: sql

I have two tables A (primary key - unit_id) and B (primary key - unit_id)

I have a value (eg :4 ) in table A and has a unit_id.

I have 4 rows in table B with the same unit ID

I have to write a SQL query to check whether the value in table A matches with the count (rows) in table B with the same unit_id

Comment: Show the structure of your tables, and what select you have so far

Comment: You are writing SQL and not a program using programming language. Also what have you done so far?

Comment: You cannot have 4 rows in the table B because you stated the unit_id is primary key.

Comment: To check, you write. How do you want the result to be presented?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use inner join and you will see how many values from table A are in table B :

```
Select a.unit_id from Table1 a inner join Table2 b on a.unit_id = b.unit_id
```

Im assumin that is what you need , because as @StanislavL pointed out, you cant have more then one unique unit_id in each table.